# Sending email with attachment

Tags: email, mail

I am trying to use the `mail` command in a script to send emails with attachment. However, although the attachment is received, the body text is not. Here is the command I used:

```
 mail -A attachment.pdf -s "Test subject" example@email.com < body_text.txt
```

The email received is only a blank email with the attachment pdf file. Is there any way to include both the attachment file and the body text?

Thanks!

Comment: Try moving the email address to the end of the command.

Comment: Have you read https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/mail.mailutils.1.html ?

Comment: Hmm moving the email address to the end still does not work... it'd still just send an empty email with the attachment. Anyway, I switched to use `swaks` after that and it seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [bug in the version of `mailutils`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mailutils/+bug/1911894). While searching I came across the [mailing list](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918806#22) where a solution was offered:

> you can use the `--mime` option as a workaround:
>
> ```
> echo "body text" | /usr/bin/mail --mime -s "some subject" -A "somefile.csv" my@email.com
> ```

This adds the body text as an attachment, but it's better than nothing!